# How do I reference multiple variables in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a script that submits multiple (30) SQL queries to Google BigQuery. What is the best way to loop through the queries? My code works but it doesn't feel very Pythonic.

I need to pass through the query name within the job_id and submit the query.

```
def run_query(query,job_id):
    try:
        query_job = client.query(query,job_id=job_id)
        polling = 1
        while query_job.done() is False:
            if "q1_" in job_id:
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Job State : {} - Polling : {}".format(query_job.state,polling))
                polling +=1 
                query_job.reload()
            else:
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Job State : {} - Polling : {}".format(query_job.state,polling))
                polling +=1 
                query_job.reload()                     
    except Conflict as err:
        print("Could not run Query.  System Message: \n{}".format(err))
        sys.exit()


q1 = """SELECT * FROM XYZ"""
q2 = """SELECT TOP 10 * FROM YZF"""
q3 = """select id from fjfj"""
q4 = """SELECT * FROM XYZ"""
q5 = """SELECT TOP 10 * FROM YZF"""
q6 = """select id from fjfj"""

query_jobs = [q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6]

q = 0

for query in query_jobs:
    randid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    q+=1
    queries = "q"+str(q)
    job_id = queries+"_"+randid
    run_query(query,job_id)
    print job_id
```

Comment: If the queries are not gonig to vary, what you are doing is the only way to do it.
If you want to access multiple variables simultaneously, you should not be thinking about using a loop. Just do it one by one manually.

Comment: There is no definite answer, but a multitude of preferences - voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine to me, you could improve upon this slightly by using `enumerate` in your loop instead of a counter:

```
for i, query in enumerate(query_jobs):
    randid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    queries = "q"+str(i)
    job_id = queries+"_"+randid
    run_query(query,job_id)
    print job_id
```

Answer (score 0):

First you could simplify your `run_query` method with something like:

```
time.sleep(20 if "q1_" in job_id else 1)
```

> This would work in python 3+, I'm not sure it will wieht 2.7, but you got the idea.

Then you should take a look at [python string formatting](https://pyformat.info/), which could really help you there.

At the end,you could have something like that:

```
query_jobs  = ["""SELECT * FROM XYZ""",
               # (...)
               """select id from fjfj"""]

for i, query in enumerate(query_jobs):
    job_id = "q%s_%s" % (i, uuid.uuid4())
    run_query(query,job_id)
    print job_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest including the queries in a dictionary outlining what each is for.

```py
QUERIES = {
   "q1_XYZ": """SELECT * FROM XYZ""",
   "q2_YZF": """SELECT TOP 10 * FROM YZF""",
   "q3_FJFJ": """select id from fjfj""",
   "q4_XYZ2": """SELECT * FROM XYZ""",
   "q5_YZF": """SELECT TOP 10 * FROM YZF""",
   "q6_FJFJ": """select id from fjfj"""
}


for job_id, query in query_jobs.items():
    run_query(query,job_id)
```

Depending on how complex this will become I'd suggest adding more attributes.  The advantage like this is if you need more complex logic in run_query you can control that via attributes rather then the job_id of the query.

```py
QUERIES = {
   "q1_XYZ": { 'query': """SELECT * FROM XYZ""", 'is_A': True, 'cost': 100 },
   << more samples >>
}

for job_id, details in query_jobs.items():
    run_query(details['query'],job_id)
```